# Open document from webpage directly in Office

Tags: ms-office, webdav, alfresco, dms

I have simple asp.net mvc web application that communicates with the Alfresco DMS thru the CMIS api (soap). I want to be able open document in Microsoft Office (lets say version 2007 and above) directly from my web page, edit this document in Office and save the document via Save button in Office to the alfresco repository.

Is there anyway to this via WebDAV protocol?

Comment: I think you probably want the [Alfresco SharePoint Protocol Integration](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/SharePoint-intro.html) rather than straight WebDAV, did you try that?

Comment: Well thanks very much, I will try it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Promoting a comment to an answer

If you want to integrate with Alfresco from within Microsoft Office, then there is a very easy way to do it, but it isn't regular WebDav. Instead, what you want is the [SharePoint Protocol Integration](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/SharePoint-intro.html). With this, Alfresco pretends to Office to be SharePoint. All the integration you normally get between Office and SharePoint then works between Office and Alfresco.

Once you've installed the SPP/Vti amp, and [suitably configured it](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/SharePoint-intro.html), then in Share you should be able to pick "Edit Online" for a document. This will fire up Office, which'll talk to Alfresco to load, save etc the document. You can then work on the document from within office, and save it back to Alfresco when you're done, just as you would do if you had SharePoint.

Comment: is there any way to do this with non-microsoft browsers and office tools (e.g. firefox and openOffice)?  Or does this alfresco functionality only work with IE and office (via activeX)?  I am asking as we have a Linux team that wants this functionality and we are considering alfresco

Comment: On Windows, it'll work with IE+Office, Firefox+Office and Chrome+Office IIRC. For OpenOffice, you'd need to use a CMIS connector to talk to the repo, which is currently being worked on by a GSOC student

Comment: Looks like CMIS support is now supported in LibreOffice... http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/wabson/2012/11/01/cmis-support-in-libreoffice-experimental-features/